# Create date column from year and doy column

Tags: postgresql, date

Is there a way to create a date column combining one column having the year as string and one column containing a date-of-year (doy) as integer?

I am aware of methods like `SELECT EXTRACT(DOW FROM TIMESTAMP '2001-02-16 20:38:40');` or `SELECT to_char(date_trunc('year', now()) + interval '169 days', 'MM/DD')` but when trying to replace the "hard coded" stings with the columns I always get some kind of an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT s.id, s.year, s.doy, 
    ((s.year||'-01-01')::date + (s.doy||' days')::interval )::date AS date

    FROM table_name AS s
```

the `(s.year||'-01-01')` or `(s.doy||' days')` concats the column value with a required string and the `::date` or `::interval` changes the resulting string type

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `make_date()` function and add the number of days directly because `date + integer` is a valid operation:

```
select make_date(s.year, 1, 1) + s.doy as date
from ...
```

Comment: make_date(s.year, 1, 1) + s.doy **- 1** as date

Comment: @Stefanov.sm: we don't know how that is stored in the column (maybe it's already zero based) - but you are right that might be necessary

Comment: You are right. I'm assuming that January 1 is day 1, which seems common.

Comment: If s.year is a string do.: `(s.year)::int`  instead of `s.year`

Comment: @Charalamm: why do you store numbers in a `varchar` (or `text`) colum? That is a **really** bad idea

Comment: For that matter why do you store `year` and `doy` as separate columns when there are [built in functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-datetime.html) to split them when needed. Even more so if you follow ISO 8601 date standard.  @Stefanov.sm common perhaps, but Jan 1 would seldom be day 1 of the year when following ISO date standard (last time was 2018 and next is 2024)